# Determine for which values of  the following system is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

9x<sub>2</sub> + kx<sub>2</sub> = 9

kx<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> = -3

I'm not sure what consistent means here or how to solve for k.

I thought it was a matrix

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  9&k&9\\
  k&1&-3
\end{array}
\right] $$

Or?

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  9&k&9&0\\
  k&1&-3&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

but I'm still not sure how to solve with gaussian elimination with the second row starting with k.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

It is $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  9&k&9\\
  k&1&-3
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now, add $-\frac{k}9$ of row $1$ to row $2$.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  9&k&9\\
  0&1-\frac{k^2}9&-3-k
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now, analyze, when does this system has a solution?

Note that consistency means that there is a solution.

Comment: would the second row be k+(-k/9) = k-(k/9)  and 1-(k^2/9) and -3+9(-k/9) ? How does that give you zero?

Comment: The first entry of the second row will be $k + \left( -\frac{k}9\right)9=k-k=0$